# Percent of total Calculation

Tags: cpq, cpq-plugins

We have scenario where we have a combination of subscription fixed products and percent of total products in our products setup.

We have a setup the fixed price products to include the calculations for percent of total products i,e we have setup the category's of percent of total  and Fixed category's to be same and checked on "Include in Percent of toal" check box for these fixed products to include the percent of total calculations.

We have a scenario where there are 3 percent of total products our of which we dont want one of them to get calculated when added to the quote having the same category fixed products.For ex: Product 1 - POT
Product2- POT

Product 3 - Fixed
Product 4-Fixed
Product 5- Fixed
When I add all the 5 products ,the calcution for Product1 should not include the Fixed Product's price calculations.Pricing engine calculates out of box for both these POT products but I dont want Product1 to get calculated .

We  have achieved for the standard Quotes (Non Segmentable) using pricing rules ,rolling summary fields and formula fields but not for  phaseable or segmented quotes.

Is the custom script (QCP) the only solution ?

Thanks in Advance !

Swetha